# Pull data from multiple databases on multiple servers

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I'm trying to create a monitoring program in PHP that will monitor mysql databases from multiple servers(on different networks).

I'm in the planning stages and I am hoping for some help to see if it's even possible with mysql.

Is there a way to "pull" data from many servers on many networks?  Does mysql support data collection like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL lets you access servers remotely via the network. And you can open as many different server connections as you want. So nothing is stopping you from doing this.

However, you can only do joins between tables on the same server, so if you do that you would have to combine the data on the client application program. If you want to join between databases on different servers, you can use the [*Federated*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/merge-storage-engine.html) storage engine. This allows you to make a database on server A appear to be on server B, and then you can join them.

Comment: I looked into Federated and it appears to be exactly what I need.  Thank you :)